# asp.net - Update div InnerHTML multiple times during a long post back

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

### asp.net - Update div InnerHTML multiple times during a long post back

I have a FileUpload control that allows for multiple files to be uploaded. When the user clicks an Upload button, I want to display a list of files to be uploaded, formatted with html to indicate which file is currently being uploaded. I want to set this html as the inner html of a div I have inside the page in an update panel. I want to keep changing this html every time I loop to the next file. The problem is, the html will only show the final result after the loop is complete, instead of showing it after each iteration of the loop. I have the div in an update panel and I call the Update() method after setting the inner html every time. Can anyone help me figure out how to update the inner html multiple times within the loop?

**Import.aspx**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" ></asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <b>Upload Files:</b>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" Width="400px" AllowMultiple="true" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="fileProgressUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="margin:20px 0px; border:1px solid black; padding:20px;">
                <div id="fileProgressDiv" runat="server"></div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

**Import.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Show files with first one in progress
    string html = "<table>";
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var postedFile in fileUpload.PostedFiles)
    {
        html += GetFileProgressHTML(GetFileName(postedFile), index == 0);
        index++;
    }
    html += "</table>";
    fileProgressDiv.InnerHtml = html;
    fileProgressUpdatePanel.Update();

    // Upload each file and indicate progress
    string completedRowsHTML = "";
    html = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < fileUpload.PostedFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        var postedFile = fileUpload.PostedFiles[i];

        ImportFile(postedFile);
        completedRowsHTML += GetFileProgressHTML(GetFileName(postedFile), false);
        html = "<table>" + completedRowsHTML;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < fileUpload.PostedFiles.Count; j++)
        {
            html += GetFileProgressHTML(GetFileName(postedFile), j == i + 1);
        }
        html += "</table>";
        fileProgressDiv.InnerHtml = html;
        fileProgressUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just created a full functional example you can check, here you can see a few very simple steps to take into account:

1) Click the button, there you create a new Thread to perfom the process simultaneously, we can say it is a process worker thread. Also we enable a Timer control, it will be executing its Tick event every 500 milisenconds.

2) Inside the process worker we perfom the calculations and set the final html in a global variable, once the process (for loop) finish, we set a flag to know the process already finished.

3) The Tick event is the process that will update the UI, you can see there we're appending the value of the global variable to content of the innerHtml, because we do not want to lose the previous content.

There are a couple more lines of HTML and C# code, but I think they are pretty easy to understand.

Note: In this example We're not using jQuery, just the ASP.NET AJAX controls included in Visual Stuido. Check carefully the ASP.NET HTML code.

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="fileProgressUpdatePanel">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <b>Upload Files:</b>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" Width="400px" AllowMultiple="true" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_OnClick" />
                <br />
                <div style="margin: 20px 0px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 20px;">
                    <div id="fileProgressDiv" runat="server"></div>
                </div>
                <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="500" Enabled="False" OnTick="Timer1_OnTick"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static string _itemTemplate = "<table><tr><td>{0}</td></tr></table>";
        private static string _newHtml = string.Empty;
        private static bool _isWorking;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnUpload_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = _isWorking = true;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    _newHtml = string.Format(_itemTemplate, i);

                    //Simulate processing time
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            })
            .ContinueWith((prevTask) =>
            {
                _isWorking = false;
            });
        }

        protected void Timer1_OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_isWorking)
            {
                Timer1.Enabled = false;
                fileProgressDiv.InnerHtml = fileProgressDiv.InnerHtml + string.Format(_itemTemplate, "Process Finished!");
                return;
            }

            fileProgressDiv.InnerHtml = fileProgressDiv.InnerHtml + _newHtml;
            _newHtml = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however, I just tried this solution and there was no luck. This time, it didn't even show the results after the final iteration of the loop. I am using a master page and I have  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> in the <head>. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @IMSsam I've just updated my answer with a full functional example

Comment: I am now having issues because the FileUpload control is in the update panel in your example. The upload button's on click is saying there are no files in the file upload control

Comment: @IMSsam that is another issue, I think the problem mentioned in this question is already answered, so you can mark this question as solved